# Uploaded large excel file but getting error SIGILL?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script which uploads excel file via XMLHttpRequest and returns jquery object.
Everything working fine with small files. I tried to upload an Excel file with 2000+ rows in it. Upload is fine, I can see perfectly formatted json when echoing it directly in the browser. The final result is to build simple html table with data from excel but it becomes `Error code: SIGILL`

Procedure:

1. Select file and upload via XMLHttpRequest
2. Pass the "response" object to javascript function which will build a table.

```
function tableBuild(productsJSON) {
    var itemsListHtml = '<table class="table table-striped table-hover mx-0 my-0 py-0 px-0 items-table" style="position:relative;">';
    itemsListHtml += '<thead style="position: sticky;top: 0" class="table-dark">';
    itemsListHtml += '<tr>';
    itemsListHtml += '<th scope="col">#</th>';
    itemsListHtml += '<th scope="col"><?= Text::get('Title'); ?></th>';
    itemsListHtml += '</tr>';
    itemsListHtml += '</thead>';
    itemsListHtml += '<tbody id="itemsListHtml">';

    $.each(productsJSON.Products,function(i,v) {
        itemsListHtml += '<tr>';
        itemsListHtml += '<td class="transition">'+parseInt(i+1)+'</td>';
        itemsListHtml += '<td class="transition"><input type="text" data-label="product_title" name="product_title['+i+']" value="'+v.title+'" /></td>';
        itemsListHtml += '<tr>';

    });
itemsListHtml += '</tbody>';
itemsListHtml += '</table>';
}
```

My problem is at the procedure 2, it looks like there is not enough memory (or smth)

here's the json (it has been cut, original one has 2000+ entries

```
{
    "responseData":{"Products":[
        {"id":null,"add_class":null,"error":null,"type_id":"1","title":"POCO X5 Pro 5G 8GB/256GB Blue EU (22101320G)","type_title":"Serial","serial":"8.6916806567786E+14","qty":1,"measure_unit_id":1,"measure_unit_title":"pcs","unit_price":289,"total_price":289},
        {"id":null,"add_class":null,"error":null,"type_id":"1","title":"POCO X5 Pro 5G 8GB/256GB Blue EU (22101320G)","type_title":"Serial","serial":"8.6916806695989E+14","qty":1,"measure_unit_id":1,"measure_unit_title":"pcs","unit_price":289,"total_price":289},
        {"id":null,"add_class":null,"error":null,"type_id":"1","title":"POCO X5 Pro 5G 8GB/256GB Blue EU (22101320G)","type_title":"Serial","serial":"8.6916806695999E+14","qty":1,"measure_unit_id":1,"measure_unit_title":"pcs","unit_price":289,"total_price":289},
        {"id":null,"add_class":null,"error":null,"type_id":"1","title":"POCO X5 Pro 5G 8GB/256GB Blue EU (22101320G)","type_title":"Serial","serial":"8.6916806696022E+14","qty":1,"measure_unit_id":1,"measure_unit_title":"pcs","unit_price":289,"total_price":289},
        {"id":null,"add_class":null,"error":null,"type_id":"1","title":"POCO X5 Pro 5G 8GB/256GB Blue EU (22101320G)","type_title":"Serial","serial":"8.691680669904E+14","qty":1,"measure_unit_id":1,"measure_unit_title":"pcs","unit_price":289,"total_price":289 }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any clues? Or I'm just using wrong technique for that?

Comment: Did you check the Error logs on the server.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sure I did. this one is not on the server side. I'm getting well formed json as output in browser (just like json I posted)
but when it comes to build html table from that json it becomes trouble

Comment: This looks like a mix of PHP and JS `<?= Text::get('Title'); ?>` Is that right?

Comment: Which browser? Did you try more than one

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, correct .. code written in PHP with jQuery. This portion is just to handle translation and it's works also.

I've tested with 100, 500 and 1000 lines and everything is fine. This is only the matter of rows count

Comment: @RiggsFolly tried in different browsers the result is the same

Comment: Did you find [this yet](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/140523666/error-code-sigill?hl=en)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for helping. I've ended up to cut some less necessary data to different object. This was totally an issue with size of the "Products" object

Comment: I assumed it would be, it was rather a large amount of data